# how to detect selenium/webdriver browsing on my site

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, headless-browser

Does anyone know how to detect selenium/webdriver browsing on my site?

I don't want to block them, just detect them.

I saw this question:
[Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)

But trying all of these on latest version didn't seem to work.

Any body knows anything else?

P.S. please don't leave answers/comments of "dont block"/"you are looking in the wrong place" - I am fully aware of what I'm asking and what will be the business logic to use it.

-- EDIT --

Things I have tested from the link above:

1. detecting cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_ key on elements, mostly on window and document but some other elements we have across the entire site.
2. Searching for `window.navigator.webdriver` always returns `undefined` instead of `true` (tested on both chrome and firefox although only firefox said to support it)
3. tested the script from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45814390/1593987

All tests were done using latest selenium, browsers (firefox and chrome), and latest webdriver plugins. for now only on windows, but will probably test ubuntu as well.

Comment: detect selenium/webdriver means browser name and versions?

Comment: I mean to know it is running from selenium/webdriver, don't even need to separate just know about it

Comment: "But trying all of these on latest version didn't seem to work." What have you tested for example?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Edited the question

Comment: Hi, do you found any solution, how to detect latest version of Silenium?

Comment: So far, no. There are a few methods to catch headless browsing, but they weren't effective with selenium

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Selenium WebDriver it's handled on a spec level.

There is a read-only JS property - `navigator.webdriver` which is `true` in case webdriver is used to control browser.

Checked with Chrome v73 - returns true.

[image]

---

References:

- Spec - https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dom-navigatorautomationinformation-webdriver
- Firefox - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/webdriver
- Chrome - https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6216034532982784